# Magento2 email template inside getting this error

Tags: magento2, error, email-templates

I am using magento2.3.0.When i fire email in frontend side than getting error in email inside

```
"CSS inlining error: DOMXPath::query(): Undefined namespace prefix in selector >> .mt-menu .col-1.megamenu > ul > li:nth-child(n+1) << in /var/www/html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php"
```

Comment: Please add your custom code

Comment: But there is not added custom code

Comment: @SaphalJha when i fire the email than getting this error in email template inside

Comment: Can you please add the line number which is showing in the error?

Comment: @SaphalJha /var/www/html/XXXX/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php on line 502

Comment: My magento version 2.3.1

Comment: running php version?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.29-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93920/discussion-between-rv-singh-and-saphal-jha).

Comment: "pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1" i set in my root file inside but getting error after apply composer command "your requiremnt not be resolved to an installable set of packages"